# External Id is not showing up in data loader field mapping

Tags: data-loader, externalid

I am trying to insert Junction object data based on External Id of the Contact. I have created an external id field as follows on Contact object:

- Name: External Id
- API: External_Id__c
- DataType: Text(20)
- External Id checkbox is selected.

Junction object has Lookup relationship to Contact with API Name Contact__c

In the data loader, it is unable to find the Contact relationship based on External Id.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

External Id field does not have FLS for System Administrator profile, That's why it was unable to see this field.

Background of the issue: Through the change set this field has been migrated to other sandbox. Normally Profiles have not been added in the change set.

So, field have migrated properly but, FLS was not available since we have not added respective profiles.

After migration, manually FLS supposed to be given (even if to the System Admin profile), which has been missed.

Comment: Happens, faced same once :)

Comment: because of migration it has been missed